# Append readmore label after 120 char, and make it clickable in ios

Tags: ios, swift

The data is coming from parser, if the text is more than 120 char then it should append "...ReadMore" just like facebook.  I have got the code for appending text, but dont know how to make clickable link. I'm using Swift Languange.

```
if cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text!.utf16Count >= 120
    {
     var abc : String =  (cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text! as 
    NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 120))
     abc += " ...ReadMore"
      cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text = abc

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mihir Mehta, This is code i have implemented.

```
    var bhikmangaTextlbl:UITextView?  
if cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text!.utf16Count >= 120
            {
                var abc : String =  (cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text! as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 120))
                    abc += "...ReadMore"
                    cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.text = abc
                var attribs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)]
                var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: abc, attributes: attribs)
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "...ReadMore", range: NSRange(location: 120, length: 11))
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 120, length: 11))
                cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.attributedText = attributedString
            }


     //The function you said i have written here
        func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
            {
                return true
            }
```

Comment: bhikmangaTextlbl is object of which class ? UITextField, UILabel or UITextView ?

Comment: it is created at UITableViewCell. var bhikmangaTextlbl:UITextView?

Comment: did that still that function isnt getting called.

Comment: done :-)  @mihirmehta forgot to comment cell!.bhikmangaTextlbl!.selectable = false because of this it wasnt working. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attributed string here ... and make some part of text clickable

here is Objective C code. You can write same for Swift

```
NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: BODY_FONT_COLOR,
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:FontHelvetica size:AppFont16]
                              };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ACCIDENT_DETECTION_AUTOMATIC_TEXT attributes:attribs];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                             value:@"Accident detection"
                             range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"Read More"]];




    NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: LINKS_FONT_COLOR,
                                     NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor],
                                     NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};

    // assume that textView is a UITextView previously created (either by code or Interface Builder)
    self.accidentDetectionText.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
    self.accidentDetectionText.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: I have created a TapGesture, i want only "...readMore" should be clickable, for now the tapGesture is taking the whole text as clickable.

Comment: remove tap gesture .... just use attributedText ... and your - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange will be called

Comment: i have tried that, but that function isnt called.func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

Comment: This code is working perfectly fine in my app... Not sure why isn't working for you ... is it UITextView right ?

Comment: Yeah, it is UITextView. Btw when you click on readMore func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool should get called rite ?

Comment: Yes ... tap for 1 sec ... don't lift your finger immediately

Comment: Nope that func isnt getting called.

Comment: tried but not getting any thing.

what i need to replace this ACCIDENT_DETECTION_AUTOMATIC_TEXT and @"Accident detection" with??

Comment: Your own text that you want to display

Answer (score 0):

Well i would prefer adding an extra label titled "Read more" and adding the tap gesture on that for expanding the first label.

Comment: i dont want to use another label.