# How to highlight text in IOS label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm new to IOS and making a instagram clone to practice IOS development.

I'm interested in one label with highlighted text on instagram's sign in page.

[image]

I have two questions about the screen shot above.

1, My guess it is one label with partial text is highlighted.

2, Only after user tap on the highlighted part, it will trigger action to move to another page.

I googled but couldn't find a way to implement this.

Another guess is this feature is from a third party library.

Do you what library could do something similar?

Thanks

Comment: for the other part of your question detecting the taps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043006/swift-tap-on-a-part-of-text-of-uilabel Make sure you search for the questions you want to ask before you ask them to avoid duplicates. There are many many questions similiar to this.

Comment: NSAttributedString maybe?