# Replacing a swift String with another string at a specific index

Tags: swift

Lets say I have a Swift string

> "Hello I'm John Doe"

I want to replace John Doe with:

> Steve.

How is that done with Swift 3?  The syntax is taking me forever to figure out.

I've tried a few things, one of them is x.replaceSubrange, but it has a syntax that I'm not able to figure out.

> x?.replaceSubrange(<#T##bounds: Range##Range#>, with: <#T##String#>)

I tried to create a range with NSRange, but it didn't like that either.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: What's so hard? `string.replacingOccurrences(of: "John Doe", with: "Steve")`

Comment: John doe can be Mary doe.  but I want to replace using an index after "I'm"

Comment: Why don't you simply do `"Hello I'm \(name)"`

Comment: The the thing is, even "Hello I'm" can be "Hi I'm" it is dynamic. It is just an example, but I need to use ranges for my example.  It's a UITextField replacement thing.

Comment: So you don't even know if the guy's (maybe compound) name has 1, 2, 3 or even more. How are you dealing with it?

Comment: Or you just want the string up to `I'm` upperbound

Comment: You should have a placeholder for name there, e.g. `$name`. All other solutions are easy to break with non-standard names. The problem is not finding the start of the name but the end of it.

Comment: @LeoDabus, the uitextFieldDelegate gives me the range, but it uses NSRange.

Comment: So your problem is converting NSRange to String Range

Comment: Compare [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25138339/2976878)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233619/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let s1 = "Hello I'm John Doe"

//Get the start of `John Doe`
if let index = s1.range(of: "John Doe", options: .literal) {
    // Take the string from start until `John Doe` append `Steve.` to it
    let s2 = s1.substring(to: index.lowerBound).appending("Steve.")
}
```

Comment: This works, but not what I'm looking for, but given my question seem a bit ambiguous, this is the most correct one.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove the substring **after** `I'm` and then **append** another string.

```
let original = "Hello I'm John Doe"
let marker = "I'm"
let newName = "Steve"

guard let startIndex = original.range(of: marker) else { fatalError() }
let result = "\(original.substring(with: startIndex)) \(newName)

// "I'm Steve"
```

Comment: Thats not the question here