# Crash when creating NSRange in String

Tags: swift, string, nsrange

I am encountering a random crash in the `NSRange` creation. Because I added a check before, I do not understand how it can happen:

```
let textStr = "whatever you want"   
if let end = textStr.unicodeScalars.index(textStr.startIndex, offsetBy: slide.endIndex, limitedBy: textStr.endIndex){
    let realEnd = textStr.unicodeScalars.index(textStr.startIndex, offsetBy: slide.endIndex)
    nsRange = NSRange(start...realEnd, in: textStr)
}
```

- `slide` is an object generated by a parser and representing a portion of `textStr`.
- Parser uses `textStr.unicodeScalars` for performances reasons

Comment: What is `slide`, what is `start`, what error message do you get?

Comment: You can't use the String Index from a different string. Btw why are you using unicodeScalars index? Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233619/2303865

Comment: Most likely it's just `start..<realEnd`

Comment: Added more context in initial question

Comment: @vadian I do not think that this is the issue (using your code does not take last char of the slide into account)

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark, you should add a reproducible example with a concrete value for `slide`. And what are the *performances reasons* you are talking about? The `String` API in Swift is highly optimized.

Comment: regarding **"using your code does not take last char of the slide into account"** comment you need to limit your method using the index before the end. Check out the `BidirectionalCollection` extension at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865 as reference

Comment: @vadian for a parser, using the String API is a dozen of time slower than using `unicodeScalars`

Answer (score 0):

This works in a Playground:

```
import Foundation

let textStr = "whatever you want"
let slide = "you"
let start = slide.startIndex // not sure what this was meant to be in your code
if textStr.index(textStr.unicodeScalars.startIndex, offsetBy: slide.unicodeScalars.distance(from: slide.startIndex, to: slide.endIndex), limitedBy: textStr.unicodeScalars.endIndex) != nil {
    let realEnd = textStr.index(textStr.unicodeScalars.startIndex, offsetBy: slide.unicodeScalars.distance(from: slide.unicodeScalars.startIndex, to: slide.unicodeScalars.endIndex))
    let nsRange = NSRange(start..<realEnd, in: textStr)
}
```

Seems like a weird way to go about this though. Perhaps rethink your approach.

Comment: What if there is more than one occurrence of "you"
 at textStr?

Comment: Btw try `let textStr = "Hello USA  !!! Hello World !!!"`and 
`let slide = "!!!"` and use the resulting range `start..<realEnd` at textStr to get a substring. `textStr[start..<realEnd]` would result  in `"Hel"`

Comment: I am not so proud of this code. Given I have the caret position in an NSTextView and a set `unicodeScalars`, what would you do?