# Simplest way to implement a "Read More" button to expand a UITextView in iOS Swift 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uitextview

I am looking to implement a "Read more" button that will expand the UITextView so that someone can read the whole text if they wish. I haven't managed to find an easy way to achieve this yet. I tried to "play" with the container's height but it doesn't give me the desired results. I would really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Check the following link, it might help
[Append readmore after 120 char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175144/append-readmore-label-after-120-char-and-make-it-clickable-in-ios)

Comment: are you useing auto layout?

Comment: "I tried to "play" with the container's height but it doesn't give me the desired results" Meaningless. Show what you did and explain what you don't like about the results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest you the ilyapuchka **ReadMoreTextView** library which is on [this](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView) link. It is the easiest way to achieve this and it is retty lightweight.

You can install it with CocoaPods, just implement `pod 'ReadMoreTextView'` into the podfile and you can use it likie this:

```
let textView = ReadMoreTextView()

textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor ..."

textView.shouldTrim = true
textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
textView.trimText = "Read more"
```

Comment: i think, you´re right. I would have responded as u ;-) Just startet to search for it...

Comment: Has any of you used it in xcode 7.3.1? Because this framework doesnt not work for me. Comes up with lots of errors when trying to compile the app. :(

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp I just added a screenshot with the errors. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @UlliH Thank you! Please let me know if you get the same errors as me :/

Comment: @UlliH Aw I use Deployment-Target 9.2. Maybe this is why I get errors. Will try again now.

Comment: @UlliH I am still getting the same errors. Very strange. :(

Comment: Oh woe, just recognized, that I´ve 9.3 :-( Sorry for that. I'll get here later...

Comment: Now definitely tested with 9.2 **and** 9.3.1: everything is fine at me!

Comment: @Tarvo Mäesepp what do u mean with podfile?

Comment: @UlliH, do you know how to use cocoapods?

Comment: @UlliH, Sorry, I had long trip to Croatia, I can help you now. I think I need your whole project or you have to learn how to use Cocoapods. it is easy.

Comment: @Tarvo Mäesepp oh, hope u had a nice time! Meanwhile i have learned about with ... **Stackoverflow** ;-) But many Thanks!

Comment: How to implement this in uiTableView cell ?