# How to expand - collapse UITextView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I was wondering if there is a possibility to display only 3 lines of text in a textview and when you click a read more button, it will expand to the whole text that contains of more then 3 lines of text. How is this possible within Swift and without any pod or plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: This could help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244707/simplest-way-to-implement-a-read-more-button-to-expand-a-uitextview-in-ios-swi

Comment: I don't want to use a external library...

Comment: @Caspert You could look at the library though and figure out what code you would want to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this without using another a 3rd-party library, the easiest way is to adjust the frame of your UITextView. In my sample code, I have a textView and a Button in my storyboard. and onReadMore is called when the button is pressed. I just use 40 as the size when it is collapsed and 200 when it is expanded.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() 
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let frame = textView.frame
    let newRect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 200, 40)
    textView.frame = newRect
  }

  @IBAction func onReadMore(sender: AnyObject)
  {
    let frame = textView.frame

    if frame.height < 180
    {
      textView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 200, 180)
    }
    else
    {
      textView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 200, 40)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the expanded height is unknown/dynamic ?

Comment: you can use the frame's height as base then add a fixed number to it.